# Groups with the subtraction operation

Tags: group-theory, modular-arithmetic

Why do integer mod integer sets with the operation of subtraction not form groups?

For example, integers mod 3 is {0,1,2}, which has an identity (0) and inverses (self inverses). And subtraction is an operation because any arguments into the operation outputs something still within integers mod 3. I suspect I am missing something as to why that is not a group.

Comment: **Hint** $ $ Subtraction is associative $\iff$  subtraction = addition, e.g. in the integers mod $2$ or any ring of characteristic $2$. See my answer for the simple proof.

Comment: thanks, that makes sense for integers mod 2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you checked associativity?

For example, is $(2-1)-1=2-(1-1)$?

Comment: thanks! i was thinking about that because i heard another explanation and got stuck thinking about how there _are_ inverses. completely forgot about associativity though.

Answer (score 2):

Subtraction is associative $\!\iff\! (x\!-\!y)\!-\!z = \overbrace{x\!-\!(y\!-\!z)}^{\textstyle x-y+z}\! \iff\! -z =z\iff\! \overbrace{x - y = x+ y}^{\!\!\!\!\!\text{subtraction}\,{\bf =}\, \text{addition}}$

Comment: What does subtraction = addition mean, here? I'm sure there is something you're trying to say here but I just don't see your point. What are you trying to say?

Comment: @Will Subtraction is associative precisely when negation is the identity operation, i.e.  $ -z = z\,$ for all $z,\,$ which is equivalent to addition being the same as subtraction, i.e. $\,x- y = x + y\,$ for all $x,y.\ \ $